# An operator in $L^2$which cannot be written as a series in the position and momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction

I have been recently checking questions about whether every operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a series in $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$, the position and momentum operators, and apparently the consensus appears to be that it is not true that every operator can be written as a function of these two.

Can one give me an example of an operator that cannot be formally written as a function of these two operators? That is, an operator $\hat{O}$ defined in a subset of $L^2$ that cannot be formally written as
$$\hat{O} = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\hat{x},\hat{p}),$$
where $f_n$ denote a sequence of functions.

I am allowing formal series here, such as $f(\hat{x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \hat{x}^n$, which would yield the operator that multiplies an $L^2$ function by the function $f(x)$. These would be weakly convergent, or could be performed with respect to some sort of generalized spectral measure.

Comment: Just a comment: the spin operator for instance, requires you to define your operators and wavefunctions in a space larger than $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, e.g. $L^2(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: How about multiplication by a non-analytic function in $L^2$?

Comment: any function in $L^2$ can be approximated by continuous functions, so we have $f(\hat{x})=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(\hat{x})$, in the sense of weak convergence.